# Multiple condition over a variable number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a pandas Dataframe with 2 fixed columns and a variable number of columns after these two. I need to change the values in the second column, depending on those of the others. The problem is that I don't know in advance how many additional columns I will have in my dataframe and I need to set a flexible way to check their value.

```
def validateAndSetSignals(self, signalsDf, datesReb):


        totSignals = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['TOT_SIGNAL','TRADING_DAY'], index = self.unqDates)
        for names in signalsDf.keys():
            tmpSign = signalsDf[names].sum(axis =1)
            totSignals[names] = tmpSign
            totSignals['TOT_SIGNAL'] = totSignals['TOT_SIGNAL'] + tmpSign




        for i in range (len(totSignals.columns) - 2):         
            totSignals.loc[totSignals[totSignals.columns[2:]] != 0, 'TRADING_DAY'] = 1
```

As you can see, `'TOT_SIGNAL'` and `'TRADING_DAY'` are the fixed columns, while I may have one or more depending on the for cycle at the beginning. Then I want to check when at least one of the additional columns is different from 0, and set 1 the column `'TRADING_DAY'`.

I am in trouble because I am not able to create specific conditions, since I don't know in advance the number and the names of the additional columns. I tried using positional indexing, since all of them will be after the second, but It does not work. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Do you really need all those columns? Have you considered using fixed number of columns and maybe fill them with lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) without `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(8), columns = ['TOT_SIGNAL','TRADING_DAY']).join(pd.DataFrame(np.eye(8, 5)))

df.TRADING_DAY = df.TRADING_DAY.mask((df.iloc[:,2:] != 0).any(axis=1), 1)
```

Result:

```
  TOT_SIGNAL TRADING_DAY    0    1    2    3    4
0        NaN           1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1        NaN           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2        NaN           1  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3        NaN           1  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
4        NaN           1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
5        NaN         NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6        NaN         NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7        NaN         NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: A really interesting approach, I timed both our answers and I got these results: for mine `3.77 ms for 100 loops` and for yours  `5.97 ms for 100 loops`. I wonder why it is taking longer for you, maybe the condition for every cells and then `any` takes longer because it creates a temporary DataFrame.

Comment: Both the solutions proposed are good, but I prefer this because I do not want to create another function. I would also consider the timing and test it, because this function is a part of a trading platform I am writing on my own. So there is the chance that one would perform really better than the other.

Comment: @SmileyProd: for large dataframes  (>> 1k rows) and relatively small numbers of columns (<100), `any` is significantly faster than `apply` (1mio rows x 100 cols: `apply` = 96 s, `any`/`mask` =  0.7 s)

Comment: You should definetly take what fits the most for you project but based on Stef's comment it seems that his way is really better which is not surprising  because it uses Pandas optimization, I was actually more surprised on what I timed. So thank you @Stef for your clarification !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on all rows by following the method below.

First define a function to see if a row has at least one value different to zero:

```
def checkRow(row):
    for x in row:
        # Equivalent to if x != 0 or if x == True
        if x:
            return 1
    # If all columns for this row is equal to 0 return 0
    return 0
```

Then you can use the apply function on all columns after the two first ones and put the result in the `TRADING_DAY` column as follows:

```
totSignals.TRADING_DAY = totSignals.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda row: checkRow(row), axis=1)
```

> To understand better the code, here is the offical documentation of all the function used:
>
> [DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html): to select the columns that you are interested in.
>
> [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html): to apply the function on every row of the DataFrame object.